# Remove string containing apostrophes python

Tags: python, string

How can I remove a string that contains apostrophes e.g.: I want to remove  `' Cannot get 'data' from cell'` from my text.
i would use `str.replace('Cannot get 'data' from cell','')`, but the apostrophes are "splitting" the string and so this doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape single quotes using the backslash like this:

```
str.replace('Cannot get \'data\' from cell', '')
```

If you want to remove both the initial quotes and the ones in the middle, you should escape the first and last too like this:

```
str.replace('\'Cannot get \'data\' from cell\'', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use double quotes to mark the string you want to remove, or use backslashes, though is more unclear.

```
string.replace("'Cannot get 'data' from cell'",'')
string.replace('\'Cannot get \'data\' from cell\'', '')
```

EDIT: If you don't have quotes before `Cannot` and after `cell`, you just need to remove first and last single quote from the string to be replaced

```
string.replace("Cannot get 'data' from cell",'')
string.replace('Cannot get \'data\' from cell', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the other answers here answered your question, but it's confusing me. In what way "remove"? If you really want to remove it:

```py
foo = 'Hello, World! This string has an \' in it!'
if "'" in foo:  # if '\'' in foo is also possible
   del foo
```

If you mean to replace the apostrophes with something try:

```py
foo = 'Hello, World! This string has an \' in it!'
foo = foo.replace('\'', parameter2) #parameter2 is the value which you wanna replace the apostrophe with
```

Please be more specific with your questions in the future!